# "to spate" as a verb

Tags: expressions, word-usage

As I was reading a book I came upon the following passage:

> And when rain at length arrives, how beneficent is its coming!
>   Boisterously, richly, merrily it **spates** forth, like the large, hot
>   tears of a man unexpectedly relieved of care; [...]

Is the verb *to spate* still being used? I checked several dictionaries but I could only find these definitions:

1. - freshet, flood
2. - a large number or amount: *a spate of books on gardening*
   - a sudden or strong outburst: *a spate of anger*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. *Spates* as a Verb**

The sentence cited in the poster's original question comes from [C. J. Hogarth's 1915 translation](http://books.google.com/books?id=UZJgAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22And+when+rain+at+length+arrives,+how+beneficent+is+its+coming!+Boisterously,+richly,+merrily+it+spates+forth,+like+the+large,+hot+tears+of+a+man+unexpectedly+relieved+of+care%22&source=bl&ots=8cpzjyjUwt&sig=GcARohbAtnLtJCQRYpe27sLrLzo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=axkdU4SSDY_ooAT5moGoBA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22And%20when%20rain%20at%20length%20arrives%2C%20how%20beneficent%20is%20its%20coming!%20Boisterously%2C%20richly%2C%20merrily%20it%20spates%20forth%2C%20like%20the%20large%2C%20hot%20tears%20of%20a%20man%20unexpectedly%20relieved%20of%20care%22&f=false) of Ivan Goncharov's novel *Oblomov*. The whole translated sentence, in context, reads as follows:

> And when rain at length arrives, how beneficent is its coming! Boisterously, richly, merrily it **spates** forth, like the large, hot tears of a man unexpectedly relieved of care; and as soon as ever it has passed the sun appears with a new smile of love, to dry the fields and the hillocks, and to cause all the countryside to assume an answering smile of delight.

Though this is the only instance of *spates* as a verb I've been able to find in Google Book searches, it invokes the same image of a flood of tears as does the 18th-century ballad  "[Jock o' the Side](http://books.google.com/books?id=2655sD39x5IC&pg=PA237&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LEAdU_28HIzkoASG84B4&ved=0CDIQ6AEwATiYAg#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false)," from *The Poetical Museum* (1784), reprinted in *Popular British Ballads: Ancient and Modern* (1894), where *spates* appears as a noun:

> For Mangerton-House Auld Downie is gane
>
> Her coats she has kilted up to her knee;
>
> And down the water wi' speed she rins,
>
> While tears in **spates** fa' fast frae her eye.

A note in the 1894 *Popular British Ballads* collection equates *spates* with *torrents*.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**2. *Spates* as a Noun Referring to Deluges**

*(The rest of my answer examines the continued use of* spates *as a noun to refer to floods. The usage is far more common today—albeit in a specialized area—than I had imagined. I also think the expansion of* spates *from a highly localized origin to scientific usage throughout the English-speaking world is interesting. However, I recognize that this part of my answer doesn't address the original question. Please don't read any farther if that's what you're looking for.)*

In the past several decades, the term *spates* (referring to powerful floods) has become quite common in technical literature in the fields of ecology and hydrology. This excerpt from Thomas L. Crisman, "[Upper Mississippi Restoration Ecology: Putting Theory into Practice](http://books.google.com/books?id=t4zSEQsgew8C&pg=PA273&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rVgfU6CfBIKIogTrgoLQDQ&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false)," in *Large-Scale Ecosystem Restoration* (2008) is fairly typical:

> Allochthonous organic matter from the riparian zone collects in headwater stream channels as wood, mixed debris dams, and leaf packs and serves as a habitat and a food source (leaves) for invertebrates. The residence time of such organic matter at a channel location and the configuration and size of individual detrital patches are reflections of the frequency and intensity of **spates**. Enhanced drainage networks within the upper watershed and stream channelization have resulted in simplification of stream channels through the scouring action of **spates**, leading to removal of all organic debris structure and a smoothing of the stream bottom.

At least two technical authors are at pains to distinguish spates from less extreme floods: G.E. Petts & C. Amoros, [*Fluvial Hydrosystems*](http://books.google.com/books?id=dyfbYsBA7WgC&pg=PA173&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rVgfU6CfBIKIogTrgoLQDQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false) (1996) offer this discussion:

> 8.3.3 HYDROLOGY AND HYDRAULICS, FLOODS AND **SPATES**
>
> Hydrology and hydraulics represent key factors in the ecology of large river systems (Statzner et al., 1988). Life in rivers and near their flood- plains are conditioned by the intensity and duration of drought and especially **spates** in the annual hydrological cycle; this is not only apparent in tropical rivers but also in the temperate regions, where their importance has been recognized only relatively recently. It is important to distinguish between exceptional **spates**, which in their intensity and frequency occur in a random manner following episodic climatic events, and the regular floods or periods of high water that result from seasonal fluctuations of the region of drainage basin. The role of floodplain annexes in these two types of situations is obviously different.
>
> During strong **spates**, which represent true perturbations, a river's aquatic annexes constitute important refuges from which fish recolonize the main channel following the **spate**. Some refugee fish remain in the annexes to feed or perhaps to replace conspecifics eliminated from the annexes during an exceptionally strong **spate**.

However, the distinction between spates and regular floods is a fairly recent development. Consider, by way of contrast, Nancy K. Sandars, [*Bronze Age Cultures in France*](http://books.google.com/books?id=l8w7AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA293&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EgkeU7TvFtfjoASYt4DwBw&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBDgU#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false) (1957):

> This was not the case formerly. The Rhone's current is largely due to an historical narrowing of the stream between artificial banks. Once it flowed through wide marshlands, and though there must always have been seasonal **spates** with the melting of the snows in the high Alps, at other times there would have been an expanse of sluggish, shallow water near the banks perfectly suitable for navigation.

An extended exploration of Google Book results strongly reinforces the Scottish origin of *spates* in the sense of floods. The dozen or so earliest instances of *spates* that my search turned up (covering a period from 1774 to 1874) are all from Scotland, starting with Thomas Pennant, [*A Tour of Scotland; 1769*](http://books.google.com/books?id=anpbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA133&dq=%22spates,+as+they+are+called%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4HYfU73gJNXhoATJwYHgDQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22spates%2C%20as%20they%20are%20called%22&f=false), third edition (1774):

> The Glen contracts, and the mountains approach each other. Quit the *Highlands*, passing, between two great rocks, called the Pass of *Bollitir*, a very narrow strait, whose bottom is covered with the tremendous ruins of the precipices that bound the road. I was informed, that here the wind rages with great fury during winter, and catching up the snow in eddies, whirls it about with such impetuosity, as makes it dangerous for man or beast to be out at that time. Rain also pours down sometimes in deluges, and carries with it stone and gravel from the hills in such quantity that I have seen the effects of these ***spates***, as they are called, lie cross the roads as the *avelennches*, or snow-falls, do those of the *Alps*.

In the second edition of his *Tour*, Pennant had used the wording "I have seen these *spates*, as they are called, lie cross the roads"; he may have added "the effects of" in the third edition to distinguish between a spate (or deluge) itself and rubble that remains after a spate dissipates.

An early figurative use of the term occurs in Robert Burns, "[On Pastoral Poetry](http://books.google.com/books?id=MpoiAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA175&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UW8fU7OMIsrdoASf9oLQDA&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAjg8#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false)" (1791):

> Thy rural loves are nature's sel';
>
> Nae bombast **spates** o' nonsense swell;
>
> Nae snap conceits, but that sweet spell
>
> O witchin' love;
>
> That charm that can the strongest quell;
>
> The sternest move.

According to a glossary appended to James Currie's edition of [*The Works of Robert Burns*](http://books.google.com/books?id=4HECAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA358&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=B28fU7WzCMiDogTdpoKgAw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAjgo#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false), volume 4 (1816), spates are "Swollen streams." But in "[Letter from John Maxwell, Esq. of Munches, to W. M. Herries, Esq. of Spottes](http://books.google.com/books?id=FrAKAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QG8fU6agDIqDogT3yIBQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAjgy#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false)" (February 8, 1811), in *The Farmer's Magazine*, (February 1815), the term *spates* has a different footnoted definition:

> During these times, when potatoes were not generally raised in the country, there was for the most part a great scarcity of food, bordering ion famine; for, in the Stewartry of Kirkcudbright, and county of Dumfries, there was not as much victual produced as was necessary for supplying the inhabitants; and the chief part of what was required for that purpose, was brought from the Sandbeds of Esk, in tumbling cars, on the Wednesdays, to Dumfries; and when the waters were high, by reason of **spates**,* and there being no bridges, so that these cars could not come with the meal, I have seen the tradesmens' wives in the streets of Dumfries, crying, because there was none to be got.
>
> *Floods.

A more detailed definition of *spates* during the term's predominantly (or purely) Scottish phase is this one from John Mctaggart, [*The Scottish Gallovidian Encyclopedia*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ivgvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA311&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1HIfU6mdL8broASP0YGQCA&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false) (1824):

> LAMMAS **SPATES**.— Those heavy falls of rain, common about *Lammas* or Midsummer. Farmers who live by the banks of waters, prepare themselves against the falling of these ***spates*** or *spouts*, by removing every thing out of the river's way ; that though it swells, and comes foaming down, it can do them no injury ; not rob them of their *wunter's fodder*.

This source's equating of *spates* with *spouts* suggests that *spates* may have originated as a Scottish spelling (and pronunciation) of *spouts*. I haven't found any confirmation of this idea elsewhere.

Evidently, in Scotland, poachers exploited spates that coincided with trout spawning season, as we see in the testimony of poachers examined during legal proceedings in 1840, reported in Robert Burns Bagg, [*The Lochleven Angler*](http://books.google.com/books?id=XuU-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA73&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FDsdU8maO5LxoAShx4D4Bw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwADiEAg#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false) (1874):

> The second [poacher] states that "he commenced when he was a boy of eight or ten years of age to fish the waters which run into Lochleven, particularly in spawning time. ...  At the tail of **spates**, when the trouts were most plentiful in the burns, and when they were chiefly poached, they were full of spawn. Thought there were as many trouts killed in the burns in winter as were killed by the nets.'' The third [poacher] states that he "had been engaged in poaching on the waters since he was a boy. ...Went almost daily during **spates**. It was necessary to go to the waters immediately after **spates**, otherwise the waters would have been cleared of the whole trouts by others."

From Scotland the term *spates* seems to have radiated to various Commonwealth possessions and protectorates, where British writers applied the term to local phenomena. For example, Gilbert Ernest Hubbard, [*From the Gulf to Ararat: An Expedition Through Mesopotamia and Kurdistan*](http://books.google.com/books?id=isEi0VwjnYAC&pg=PA226&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xm8fU5zaL8zroATio4KwBA&ved=0CFoQ6AEwCDg8#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false) (1917) (published in Edinburgh):

> The Zab being a snow-fed river, liable to sudden **spates**, it is quite likely that the original bridge-builders deliberately omitted the arches or anything that would tend to dam the stream, leaving it to the local Kurds to throw across a temporary wooden structure which could be easily replaced.

And A. B. Lennie, "[Agriculture in Mesopotamia in Ancient and Modern Times](http://books.google.com/books?id=xp4oAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA476&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-wYeU7qFCdXZoAT3-oGADA&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBThG#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false)," in *Scottish Geographical Magazine* (January 1936), cited in *Bibliography on Soil Erosion and Soil and Water Conservation* (1938):

> The great difficulty in Iraq is the excessive amount of sediment in the water during **spates**, leading to heavy silting whenever the velocity of the current is checked. This difficulty is minimised in the case of modern canals by ensuring slack-water where they head off.

And Hans Burger, [*Indian Forest Records: Silviculture*](http://books.google.com/books?id=QZBYAAAAMAAJ&q=%22spates%22&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OgAeU8GbAcOJogSsrIGYAQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCDgy), volume 6 (1946):

> II. The effect of the forest on **spates**.
>
> The forest can contribute both directly and indirectly to minimize **spates**. Directly, the forest keeps back a considerable part of the precipitation as "sprinkle" water in the tops of the trees which evaporates. The tree trunks with their buttresses, the boughs, twigs, leaves and needles which lie on the ground slow down the surface run-off, thus favouring infiltration.

And James Russell Andrus & Azizali F. Mohammad, [*The Economy of Pakistan*](http://books.google.com/books?id=9puaAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AQweU7vHBsL-oQTU3YCwDg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBTge#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false) (1958):

> This area and a part of central Bengal is a land of 'dead or dying rivers', and silt-bearing waters no longer flow through the numerous channels in the region; their place has been taken by large swamps and inland lakes, called *beels* or *haors*. When there are heavy rains in the Himalayas, 'enormous **spates** of water rush through the narrower and shallower streams' of this and other regions, and the surrounding countryside is inundated by severe floods. Despite these periodic rampages, the rivers of East Bengal 'contribute richly to the life an wealth of the province'.

The quotations in the above extract are drawn from *Census*, volume 3 (1951).

In books from recent decades, I found only one mention of *spates* in connection with fishing in Scotland—in Malcolm Greenhalgh, [*Atlantic Salmon: An Illustrated Natural History*](http://books.google.com/books?id=NePk6fN6xooC&pg=PT36&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZGwfU4XTItbsoASoyoI4&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAjigAQ#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false) (2005) —which may signal a decline in the term's usage in its place of origin. (The term also appears in the Scottish Canoe Association's guidebook, [*Scottish White Water*](http://books.google.com/books?id=op49hh6-FiQC&pg=PA83&dq=%22spates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aGofU4iKDIjAoASpuoHYCg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBTiCAQ#v=onepage&q=%22spates%22&f=false) (2004), though with a paddler's focus on the water level and navigability of streams.) But while *spates* may now be rare or obsolete among Scottish cottagers and anglers (and poachers), it has become firmly established as a technical term among present-day hydrologists and ecologists.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the OED, nor Oxford Dictionaries generally, recognise 'spate' as a verb, in either of its meanings.

Oxford Dictionaries gives two meanings of the noun:

1. a large number of similar things coming in quick succession: *a spate of attacks on holidaymakers*
2. chiefly BRITISH a sudden flood in a river.

Now the OED which is the authoritative dictionary of the *history of English* gives no example of meaning 1 more recently than 1861. This seems nonsensical because, although it is perhaps not an everyday expression, in my own experience it is far from obsolete.

However in respect of meaning 2. it also gives nothing more recent than 1871. But in this case it would seem to me reasonable as I do not recall ever hearing it used in that way.

According to the OED meaning 2 (above) is, or was originally, especially associated with Scotland and the North of England.

Comment: The OED doesn't attempt to document the last use of a phrase (perhaps because the correct answer would be 'five seconds ago'); merely the first usage in a particular sense.

Comment: @TimLymington All the ones I have looked at hitherto, have quotations dating from earliest use, often as far back as the 13th century, to well into the 20th century. It is unusual, in my experience, for the quotations to stop in mid-19th century.